# Nuget installs EntityFramework 6.0.1 to .NET 3.5 class library

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5, nuget

I am rather confused about the behaviour of Nuget Package manager and Entity Framework. As far as I have been seraching, Entity Framework supports only version 3.5 in .NET 3.5 (which was shipped with the .NET SP1). However, when I run Nuget Package it offered me to install EF 5 and today (upgrade to) EF 6.0.1. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the project is a class library with target framework .NET 3.5.

My questions:

a) Can you use EF 5 or 6 with .NET 3.5? - My answer is no as well as some other answer in here.

b) How is it possible that Nuget offers me to download these versions?

c) I downloaded EF 5 with Nuget and it worked. How is that possible? (Even on EF website they say it is only for .NET 4.0 and higher)

Comment: I'm starting to think, that it simply adds the package config, downloads the EF but then it does not use the reference and I'm using references added by Visual Studio for the original EF 3.5. That would actually explain a lot.

Comment: Hint: Get the nupkg file "MyPackage.nupkg".  Change the "nupkg" to "zip", and then look around.       That'll show you (by seeing the /lib/ subfolders) what the targeting is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We, the Entity Framework team, decided not to fix this issue (See [Work Item 1341](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1341))

Only the version of System.Data.Entity.dll that ships with .NET Framework 3.5 will work with projects that target .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. So I guess I was right in my comment to the question.